# Does anyone know why atan2 isn't working?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I talked to my professor but he told me I needed to use `atan2` instead of `atan` but when I do I just get errors. The project is converting to and from polar and rectangular angles.

```
   theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value

   * a = m; //used to assign the values to  temp/pointer variables
```

This is the error message I am getting.

```
designProject2.cpp: In function ‘void RectToPolar(float*, float*)’:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘atan2(float)’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++config.h:528,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/cassert:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:33,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:59:1: note: candidate: ‘double atan2(double, double)’
   59 | __MATHCALL (atan2,, (_Mdouble_ __y, _Mdouble_ __x));
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:59:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_Constant, std::_ValArray, _Tp, _Tp>, _Tp> std::atan2(const typename std::valarray<_Tp>::value_type&, const std::valarray<_Tp>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_ValArray, std::_Constant, _Tp, _Tp>, _Tp> std::atan2(const std::valarray<_Tp>&, const typename std::valarray<_Tp>::value_type&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::valarray<_Tp>’ and ‘float’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_ValArray, std::_ValArray, _Tp, _Tp>, _Tp> std::atan2(const std::valarray<_Tp>&, const std::valarray<_Tp>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::valarray<_Tp>’ and ‘float’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Dom> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_Constant, std::_Expr, typename _Dom::value_type, _Dom>, typename _Dom::value_type> std::atan2(const typename _Dom::value_type&, const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Dom> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_Expr, std::_Constant, _Dom, typename _Dom::value_type>, typename _Dom::value_type> std::atan2(const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>&, const typename _Dom::value_type&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>’ and ‘float’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Dom> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_ValArray, std::_Expr, typename _Dom::value_type, _Dom>, typename _Dom::value_type> std::atan2(const std::valarray<typename _Dom::valarray>&, const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Dom> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_Expr, std::_ValArray, _Dom, typename _Dom::value_type>, typename _Dom::value_type> std::atan2(const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>&, const std::valarray<typename _Dom::value_type>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>’ and ‘float’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/valarray:603,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:95,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Dom1, class _Dom2> std::_Expr<std::__detail::_BinClos<std::_Atan2, std::_Expr, std::_Expr, _Dom1, _Dom2>, typename _Dom1::value_type> std::atan2(const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>&, const std::_Expr<_Dom2, typename _Dom2::value_type>&)’
  548 | _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_FUNCTION(atan2, _Atan2)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/valarray_after.h:548:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Expr<_Dom1, typename _Dom1::value_type>’ and ‘float’
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:41,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:155:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Up> constexpr typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type std::atan2(_Tp, _Up)’
  155 |     atan2(_Tp __y, _Up __x)
      |     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:155:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
designProject2.cpp:80:29: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   80 |    theta = atan2 ( * b / * a); //used to calculate the theta value
      |                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/stdc++.h:41,
                 from designProject2.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:148:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr long double std::atan2(long double, long double)’
  148 |   atan2(long double __y, long double __x)
      |   ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:148:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:144:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr float std::atan2(float, float)’
  144 |   atan2(float __y, float __x)
      |   ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:144:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

When I use normal atan, I dont get an error, but I do get an incorrect result.

When entering

```
r -40 -30 
p 75 -150
q
```

The expected result is

```
REC -> POL +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 REC: X =  -40.00 Y =  -30.00 POL: M =   50.00 A = -143.13
POL -> REC +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 POL: M =   75.00 A = -150.00 REC: X =  -64.95 Y =  -37.50
```

But the result I am getting is.

```
REC -> POL +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 REC:  X =  -40.00 Y =  -30.00 POL:  M =  50.00 A =  36.87
POL -> REC +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 POL:   M =  75.00 A =  -150.00 REC:   X =  -64.95 Y =  -37.50
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The error message even says `candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided`. I know it's verbose, but please _try_ to read error messages and understand what they're saying. They're supposed to help you.

Comment: You might consider not using excessive whitespace around `&` and `*` when taking the address of a value or dereferencing a pointer. It makes your code more difficult to read IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background and problem:**

[**`atan`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan) requires a single value for the tangent value.
This value (being a tangent) is the ratio of `y / x`.

But this value will be the same when e.g. both `x` and `y` are positive, and when they are both negative (or when one is positive and the other negative, no matter which is which). But the actual arc tangent should be different.

**Solution:**

This problem is solved by [**`atan2`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2).
It requires both the `y` and the `x` separately and therefore can keep the distinction e.g. between 2 positive and 2 negatives etc.

In order to use it supply it with the 2 arguments, e.g.:

```
theta = atan2(*b, *a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `atan2` takes two parameters: the numerator and the denominator. When calling `tan(a / b)`, you should call `tan2(a, b)` to consider edge cases.